# Add values from multiple ranges to email body

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a piece of basic excel to email code however, i want to know how i can make it so that it can add several different cells to the body of the email. This needs to include a few ranges as well. These ranges should only display values from cells that actually contain a value, not blank ones.

E.g. 
So i'd like for example

- B12 data 
  (line break x 2)
- E15:E20 Data
  (LineBreak x2)
- F19:F20 Data

My code as it stands is:

```
Sub Send_to_Email()
On Error GoTo PROC_EXIT
Dim OL As New Outlook.Application

Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set olMail = OL.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Dim SrcSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Set SrcSheet = Sheets("Clean (2)")

With olMail
    .To = SrcSheet.Range("A19").Text
    .Subject = SrcSheet.Range("F19").Text
    .Body = SrcSheet.Range("B19").Text
    .Display vbModal
    '.Send
End With

PROC_EXIT:
On Error GoTo 0
Set OL = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: what do you want to do with these cells? Use them for your `To, Subject, Body` fields?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking into using [HTMLbody](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb175500%28v=office.12%29.aspx) instead of `body`. Then you can freely add your `<br/>` or any other formatting you want.

As an added bonus, you don't need to worry about your whitespace as you build the body string. Though obviously, you'd still want it legible as you work out your problem.

As for the ranges, check all the relevant cells and include something like:

```
If Range.value <> "" then
    'Do Stuff 
end if
```